# Delete S3 objects using snowflake query

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are using storage integration to unload data in AWS S3 Bucket. This is an external stage.
Below is the command which we are using

```
COPY INTO s3://mybucket/data/files/20210922 FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME)
                                STORAGE_INTEGRATION = SI_NAME
                                FILE_FORMAT=(TYPE=parquet)
                                MAX_FILE_SIZE=32000000
                                OVERWRITE=TRUE
                                SINGLE=FALSE
                                HEADER=TRUE
```

Is there any way to drop these files from s3 using storage integration or any snowflake query?

Any guidance would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the REMOVE command or its synonym RM to do that:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/remove.html#remove

Comment: HI Greg, Thanks for your answer. As you can see, I have not used any stage location in my query .So, Can we drop objects from external cloud location without any stage?

Comment: You will need to define an external stage to use the remove command.